# R CMD CHECK --as-cran failing on OS X Catalina

Tags: r, build, macos-catalina, cran

I am building a new R package on an iMac w/ Catalina. I have installed the latest XCode and XQuartz.
My new package builds fine, i.e.

```
R CMD BUILD conicFit
```

runs without error.  Then  I tried

```
R CMD CHECK  --as-cran conicFit
```

and get this error:

```
* using log directory ‘/Users/cgw/Rgames/fitConic.Rcheck’
* using R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* using option ‘--as-cran’
* checking for file ‘fitConic/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* this is package ‘fitConic’ version ‘1.0’
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ...Error:  file './DESCRIPTION' does not exist
Execution halted
```

If I run without the `--as-cran` flag, the check passes with no errors or warnings.
What's even more frustrating is that  I can re-run older packages and do not get this error, which suggests that the actual error is something other than not finding "./DESCRIPTION" .

Any ideas as what to test, or what to reinstall, etc.?

Comment: Why should we assume that you are not missing a DESCRIPTION file? More expansively, this sort of problem is more likely to be addressed constructively with a link to the package code on Github, so people do not need to do the "20 questions" sort of game to narrow down the possible sources of error.

Comment: @IRTFM Well for one thing, there's that line "**checking for file 'fitConic/DESCRIPTION' ok**"

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a subtle change in the way `R CMD CHECK` works under R 4.X caused commands that previously worked to fail.  The solution is to specify the tarball, i.e.

```
R CMD CHECK --as-cran fitConic.tar.gz
```

runs the detailed code check to completion.

Comment: No, that has been _the_ recommendation for many many years how.  As in "likely close to a decade".  Not an R 4.0.0 change.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  That's true.  What I meant is that, prior to my upgrading to 4.0,  I could run   `--as-cran` checks on the source files.  That no longer works.